# radio button is showing with extra outline in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is my code for radio button

```
<div class="question">
    <label for="gender" style="display: none">Gender</label>
    <fieldset class="two-radio">
        <legend>Gender</legend>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" class="radioInput" 
                ng-model="namedInsured.gender" value="Male" required> Male
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" class="radioInput" 
                ng-model="namedInsured.gender" value="Female" required> Female
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Its working finr in chrome but for IE its showing dotted outline and in firefox when you select radio button than it shows outline but after going to next element its not.
I also have other radio button in same page with same problem.
So can anyone help me with removing these outlines?
Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Have you tried the outline property CSS [W3Schools Outline](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)

Comment: @Billy I tried outline-color: #ffffff; but thats not working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. So the problem was in firefox it was outline while in IE it was border.

So in order to remove both I have to put

border: none;
outline: none;
in my stylesheet and vola... everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium adds an outline to focused elements, even grouping elements like div's.... I'm surprised that it is happening in IE and Gecko and not webkit......

your stylesheets must be using -webkit prefixes....(use the webkit developer tool to trace the style rules on your elements... anything with a -webkit- prefix is proprietry to webkit browsers.

to remove outlines on focus elements use

*:focus{outline:none}

in your bootstrap css.

Comment: I tried that. Not working. May be you can suggest me exact place, could be the reason that I am putting it on a wrong place